# New Hard Drive beeps once when started

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure

I just bought a new SATA hard drive (the Samsung HN-M101MBB) and connected it to my pc via a external drive reader (the Sharkoon Quickport), when I turned the docking station power on the hard drive beeped once. If I turn the power off and then back on again the hard drive beeps once everytime. I have connected the drive to the inside of my PC and the drive still makes this single beep when the PC starts up.

Is this normal? Why is this happening?

- It is more like a lower pitched 'dun' noise than a high pitched beep, but definitely coming from a speaker in the HDD
- This noise happened the very first time I powered on the drive, so overheating is not an issue.
- I have run the SeaTools' 'Short Drive Self Test' and it passed.

Thanks
Ben

Comment: This behaviour happens when the new HDD is connected on another computer? If you remove the HDD the noise disappears? What does the user manual says?

Comment: @ruda.almeida I have not tried the new HDD on a different computer, but it happened when it was brand new (contained no data) and was connected externally and when I mirrored my internal drive on to it and placed it inside my laptop.

Comment: Hard drives don't beep, man. I say this at the risk of making a fool out of myself, because I don't know anything about your drive, but I'm willing to take that risk and repeat: Hard drives do not beep. At any rate, it is not normal. Forgive me for being so assertive about this, as I'm sure there is nothing wrong with your hearing... Would you be so kind as to humor us with a video/audio recording of that beep? It seems like you're trying to play a joke on someone, to be honest.

Comment: ha well, if that is the case then I guess it can not be a signal that the HDD has an error. I have contacted Seagate so perhaps we will both learn something new here.

Comment: This happened to me when the external SATA to USB was loose.Also it could be not enough power for the drive

Answer (score 1):

The only way to solve this problem is to:

## Perform an exorcism

...or read about the [PC speaker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_speaker#BIOS_error_codes)

Comment: Sure, and the PC speaker is somehow located on the HDD? Or was it dormant and the new HDD woke it up?

Comment: When the HDD was connected to my laptop via an external SATA to USB cable it still made this noise, and the noise definitely came from the new HDD which was sitting on my desk attached via the USB. Does the PC Speaker still apply in this situation? As I say, the noise definitely came from the HDD connected externally.

Comment: No, the PC speaker definetely doesn't apply in this case as it is a hardware component located in the inside of the computer case. It looks either like this http://www.baybeamer.com/images/cables/InternalSPK.JPG or like this http://cdn.overclock.net/b/ba/ba4225be_speaker.jpeg and is connected directly into the motherboard.

Comment: @ruda.almeida okay, so what would cause the HDD to beep like this. Is it normal for HDD's to emit error codes in beeps like the PC Speaker does?

Comment: @BenJackson Do you have the user manual for the HDD? I couldn't find it on Google.

Comment: @ruda Yes, I believe this is the manual: http://www.seagate.com/files/www-content/support-content/internal-products/spinpoint-m-series/en-us/100698035e.pdf

It mentions the model number: ST1000LM024 which is interchangeble with the other model number number HN-M101MBB

Comment: The user manual doesn't mention any beeper or any sequence of beeps in a troubleshooting section (it doesn't even have a troubleshooting section). Weird.

Comment: Ha yes I agree. Can I just ask, is it normal for HDD to make beeping sounds when they have a problem? Or is this very unusual?

Comment: Thank you for your help so far @ruda.almeida I have now contacted Seagate/Samsung and hope they will have something to say.

Answer (score 1):

What you *may* be hearing is a small, short, high-pitched elecronic 'sqeal', rather than a beep *per se*.

I've personally heard this before, more with older 3.5" disks, but I suspect this is what you're hearing - though I can't be sure without an audio recording!

Can't find any references right now (on the road) but I would hazard a guess that it's caused by the platters spinning up and/or the read head motor.